# Help with cPanel and sending email

Tags: hosting, smtp

I've been working a wordpress site that is now hosted on cPanel (not my choice) and I'm having a really difficult time getting cPanel to send out email to an email address.

This isn't helped by the hosting company being absolute *******, offering no guidance whatsoever.

I can see the emails are being sent but they are being stored in the webmail account but I want these to be sent to my client's email account via there desktop email client.

The problem that I have is that I'm trying to forward to an email address that is on the same domain and I can't get it to work no matter what I try.

With my limited knowledge I'm guessing that their desktop email client needs to be setup with the smtp settings to connect to the hosting server, does that sound correct?  Or should I be able to forward email from the webmail?

Any help would be greatly received.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I run into email sending problems, the solution is SMTP. You can set up a free account with [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) and install WP Mail SMTP. I believe SendGrid is a free option in that plugin as well.

WP Mail SMTP has [instructions on how to configure SendGrid](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-sendgrid-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/).

Once you've configured SendGrid and installed WP Mail SMTP on your WP site, you can walk through the plugin's wizard to configure. It is pretty easy to use and will have a test feature for you as well.

Because it's all free, though somewhat time consuming, I recommend giving this a shot. Having SMTP email is more reliable, and SendGrid has statistics that can help you troubleshoot if you get reports of emails being blocked or bounced.